# What happened to Oscar Wilde in Wilde Life?

Tags: webcomics

In the webcomic Wilde Life, we're given some hints about the protagonist's backstory, but I'm having some trouble assembling them.

There's this three-page recollection where Oscar tells us he had a quiet, polite breakup with his fiance: [Wilde Life - 471](https://www.wildelifecomic.com/comic/471).

Then there's this flashback full of more alarming images: a wedding, an IV, an angry person shouting, a...  a dog? [Wilde Life - 495](https://www.wildelifecomic.com/comic/495).

In the next page, someone says: "No! Dad, it's your fault" but it's hard to identify who or why: [Wilde Life - 496](https://www.wildelifecomic.com/comic/496).

What can we conclude about Oscar's backstory?